# How Can I Get This List to Print Repeated Values in an Array Without Printing the Value Twice

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
 public static void printOrganizedList(int[] array) {
    int[] temp = array;
    System.out.println("N        Count");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(array[i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for(int n = i-1; n > 0; n--) {
            if(array[n] == array[i]) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(array[i] + "        " + count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method is made to take in an array and print the duplicate values along with the amount of times it appears in the array.  Like this:

```
     -12, 3, -12, 4, 1, 1, -12, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, -12

    The program output should be:

    N        Count

    4               2

    3               3

    2               2

    1               4

    -1             1

    -12          4
```

My issue is that no matter what I try the method always spits out the duplicate number along with its amount of repeats as many times as it is repeated.  So instead of outputting

```
    "-12        4"
```

It will output :

```
    "-12        4"
    "-12        4"
    "-12        4"
    "-12        4"
```

Also I'm aware that there are more advanced and efficient techniques but we haven't learned a lot of that stuff yet.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to use HashMap to store the count/frequency of the number in the input array?

Comment: We're allowed to use anything I believe, but I just wont be able to justify my use of hashmaps to him in the case that he asks since we haven't done them yet.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily acheived using a HashMap. You can create a Hashmap which would save the element as key and keep the number of occurrences as the value.

```
public static void printOrganizedList(int[] array) {
    System.out.println("N        Count");

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        if (countMap.containsKey(array[i])){
            int count = countMap.get(array[i]);
            countMap.replace(array[i], count + 1);
        }else{
            countMap.put(array[i], 1);
        }
    }

    Iterator iterator = countMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        int key = (int) mapElement.getKey();
        int count = (int) mapElement.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + "        " + count);
    }
}
```

Also the time complexity of the program that you have written goes to O(N^2) which can be a really big bottleneck when it comes to large programs.

The above program with hashmap implementation would only cost you O(N)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printOrganizedList(new int[] { -12, 3, -12, 4, 1, 1, -12, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, -12 });
    }

    public static void printOrganizedList(int[] array) {
        System.out.println("N\tCount");
        Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (freq.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(array[i])))
                freq.put(Integer.valueOf(array[i]), freq.get(Integer.valueOf(array[i])) + 1);
            else
                freq.put(Integer.valueOf(array[i]), 1);
        }

        for (Integer key : freq.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + freq.get(key));
        }
    }
```

, output

```
N       Count
-12     4
1       4
2       2
3       3
4       2
```

, Another solution to match your code

```
    public static void printOrganizedList(int[] array) {
        System.out.println("N\tCount");
        Arrays.sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;

            // calc freq
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count > 1)
                System.out.println(array[i] + "\t" + count);
            i += count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The nested loop may be improved: `for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) { if (array[i] != array[j]) break;  count++;}`

Comment: I have a question regarding the calc freq part.
Whenever I enter a number only once it will completely ignore that number.  So if I were to enter {1, 8 , 1, 8, 4} it would print 1 and 8 accurately but wont print 4 at all, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the range of the input array is reasonable (for instance, from -12 to 12, not from Integer.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE), you may apply count sorting:

- define min and max values in the array,
- count the frequencies,
- and print out the numbers whose frequencies are greater than 1:

```
int min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
   else if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
}
int[] freq = new int[max - min + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   freq[min + i]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
    if (freq[min + i] > 1) {
        System.out.println((min + i) + "  " + freq[min + i]);
    }
}
```